# Using gradio with http2, due to google cloud run request size limit

Tags: file-upload, google-cloud-run, http2, memory-limit, gradio

I have an application which runs as a service in google cloud run.
The app is written in python and uses gradio for its interface.
The app allows the user to upload videos for some purposes but I encountered a problem with heavy videos (or many light videos) because google cloud run has a file upload limit of only 32MB per request.

So I'm trying to bypass this problem, I found information which claims that using http2 can solve it (https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas), and it is possible to configure "Use HTTP/2 end-to-end" in google cloud run revision, but there it seems like gradio does not supports http2 (maybe I can do a work around with reverse proxy?)

More information about the process: when I'm uploading a video using Gradio it automatically saves it in a **tmp** folder, when it's too big (one big video or few videos that their sizes sums up to 32MB or more) it just loads forever.

Maybe I should try a completely different approach in order to solve this issue?

I'll be happy to hear any advice, thanks!!

I expected to upload a file larger than 32mg to app running on google cloud run, but it failed due to request limit.